# Looking for Literary technique's name

Tags: literary-techniques

What is it when an author starts the book with a future event, goes on for maybe a paragraph or a page, then stops and returns to the present?

Comment: You might have better luck on [r/tipofmytongue](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue). Identification questions are rarely helpful to future visitors.

Comment: For the downvoters:  How would "research" answer this question when one doesn't have access to some rare volume listing literary techniques?

Comment: @HotLicks Agreed. This is one of the less appealing aspects of the site. I am tempted to ask for an old word for "a drop of mucus on the nose" and see if the downvoters argue successfully that I could have done successful research first.

Answer (score 3):

This is an initial *Flash-forward* or *prolepsis*. The device may be used at any point in a tale (except at the end) and applies to your context.

> A *flash-forward* (or *prolepsis*, also sometimes known as a *flash-ahead*) in a narrative occurs when the primary sequence of events in a story is interrupted by the interjection of a scene representing an event expected, projected, or imagined to occur at a later time. The flash-forward technique is used less frequently than its reverse, the flashback, or the flash-sideways.
>
> [LostPedia](https://lostpedia.fandom.com/wiki/Flash-forward)

You may also like

> *foreshadowing* : an indication of what is to come
>
> "If the history of the world were a novel, the events so strikingly chronicled in the photographs in this book … would seem a foreshadowing of the recent events …"
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foreshadowing)

Answer (score 0):

Narrative hook.

In medias res.

Non-linear storytelling.

Framing device.

Comment: You should include definitions for each of these terms.